# Selenium Webdriver: Fallbacks for Wait Timeout Exceptions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

I'm currently using Selenium WebDriver (ran through node.js) to scrape a bunch of weather data dispersed over several decades (since the site only loads one day's worth of data per page at my desired full resolution!). An integral part of the process thus involves jumping between URLs, waiting for the appropriate data table (if applicable) to load for the page of each corresponding date.

While my current approach works for the vast majority of pages, using the explicit waiting method `await driver.wait( until.elementsLocated( By.css( #myDataTableOfInterest)), 10000)`, there are occasional periods with no available data (where the website omits the table element altogether), thus also triggering a TimeOut error on my scraper (since the non-existent table obviously can't be found!) that unfortunately also halts my entire program.

I assume however there must be some fairly standard fallback built into Selenium's waiting methods that lets you run alternative code (or simply move on to the rest of the test - perhaps with some log) in case an expected condition doesn't materialize after the specified waiting time?

My original thought was to bypass it by attaching `.then(<some empty/log function>,error => {continue})` (since this code is happening in a loop that iteratively updates the day URL) but it appears that the "continue" operation isn't valid if it's nested inside a function within the loop..

Comment: Can't you catch it the normal way with `.catch()` ?

Comment: You're correct that the catch extension does allow me to run the contingent code inside (hence the upvote) , but the script still seems to terminate unless I cleverly call some function that brings me back "on track" to the program (which is especially finicky inside a loop function). I was yearning for a canonical "clean" solution that ignored specific exceptions like fluentWait https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/ (such as Python's ignored_exceptions: NoSuchElement) but alas no equivalent seems to exist in Javascript for the time being :/

Comment: I don't have anything to suggest without seeing some code but I think you should consider to switching to Puppeteer because you'll get better answers here.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    await driver.wait( until.elementsLocated(By.css( #myDataTableOfInterest)), 10000);
}
catch (e) {
    console.log('Element not found');
}
```

You can try catching the error and doing what ever you want to handle it.

Comment: Much appreciated! I've used "try... catch" blocks so little, it didn't even occur to me I could nest another set here (where my code already resides inside another "try" block). This one allows me to put "continue" in the catch block to keep the loop going!

Comment: Do you know if selenium webdriver has built-in methods for ignoring exceptions in the javascript version (like it does for other languages (as shown in https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#fluentwait)? I guess that was sort of the original thrust of my question (perhaps I didn't word it as clearly as I could have). If you have any clarification on that, I will happily accept your answer as the definitive one for this thead (or feel free to let me know if you think this should be a separate question!)